# CSS Vertical Centering with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css

Can someone please help me and try to explain the code they put to vertically center my example? It would be a extreme help and I would appreciate it so much!

I am using Twitter Bootstrap and I need the two columns

```
.login-carousel-container
.loginbox-container
```

vertically aligned on my page.

Link To My Current Page: http://kmgp.us/stackoverflow/index.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.

Comment: How? I am simply asking how I can vertically align those two divs?

Comment: use this fiddle to help:  http://jsfiddle.net/n8d8X/

Comment: @KevinM.Gilbert Read my comment again - _include a minimal example in the question itself_. Your question includes no HTML or CSS. If your link dies your question has no meaningful information. See [ask].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use absolute positioning with transform translate to achieve this.

`.login-container {
    width:100%;
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}`

This will align the whole container to the center of the page. You can add width to ensure the container is the size you want.

EDIT:
So you want to vertically center the loginbox-container too? heres the code

`.loginbox-container {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
    transform: translate(0%, -50%);
}`

Comment: That works great! But then the right section is still not in the center. Its in the top of login-contaier

Comment: Apply these rules to the .login-container rather than .login-carousel-container

Comment: I did, and I just updated the code on the site with that code. It centers everything good, but the class loginbox-container to be vertically centered as well.

Comment: Okay I have updated my solution with this.